# react-native mobx call action from provider class

Tags: react-native, mobx-react

I have set up a very simple mobx store class:

```
import {observable, action} from 'mobx'

class TestStore {
  @observable placeholder = 'Search In Me';

  @action changeName(name) {
this.placeholder = name;
  }
}

export default new TestStore();
```

My parent class (below) is where the provider is set. The problem is in this class I also need to track the route name of the current tab that is active. That all works fine - my issue is how do I call the changeName function in the store from the parent class? Currently this.props.store.changeName is returned as undefined.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Root, Tabs } from './config/router';
import { Alert,View } from 'react-native';

import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';
import TestStore from './config/TestStore';

import {observer} from "mobx-react/native";



@observer class App extends Component {


_getCurrentRouteName(navState) {

if (navState.hasOwnProperty('index')) {
    this._getCurrentRouteName(navState.routes[navState.index])

} else {
    if (navState.routeName==='Tab 1') {
        Alert.alert('Tab 1')
        this.props.store.changeName('Tab 1')
    }
    if (navState.routeName==='Tab 2') {
        Alert.alert('Tab 2')
    }
    if (navState.routeName==='Tab 3') {
        Alert.alert('Tab 3')

    }
    if (navState.routeName==='Tab 4') {
        Alert.alert('Tab 4')

    }

}

}

  render() {
    return (

     <Provider store={TestStore}>
    <Root onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, newState) => {
        this._getCurrentRouteName(newState)

    }}  />
     </Provider>

    )


  }
 }

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved this issue restructuring my app and moving everything up a level - index.js became the following and imported the original classes in index.js back in:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';
import TestStore from './config/TestStore';


import Base from './app';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (

    <Provider store={TestStore}>
    <Base />
     </Provider>

    )


  }
}

export default App;
```